# How to write JavaScript code inside html attributes in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
return(
  <div>
    <Loading loadingMessage="Running "{this.state.programName}" program"/>
  </div>
);
```

I know that above attribute `loadingMessage` value is syntactically wrong. But my need is, I need to get that `programName` from state and append to `loadingMessage` attribute value. How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write javascript inside the curly brackets, just concatenate the string in there.

```
return (
    <div>
        <Loading
            loadingMessage={"Running " + this.state.programName + " program"}
        />
    </div>
);
```

or use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<Loading loadingMessage={`Running ${this.state.programName} program`}/>
```